# Java equivalent from Obj C

Tags: java, objective-c

What is the equivalent of this objc line in java?

```
uint64_t lInt = 0xFFFFFFFF << 10;

lInt = ((uint64_t)mBytes[0] << 24) + ((uint64_t)mBytes[1] << 16);
```

I wrote it like this but I think it is wrong.

```
long lInt = 0xFFFFFFFFL << 10;

lInt = ((mBytes[0] << 24) + (mBytes[1] << 16);
```

Comment: What are the data types for `lInt` and `mBytes[]`?

Comment: Just change **uint64_t** to **long**, everything else is the same. The capacity of long may not be enough (as there are no unsigned in Java), but that's the best you can get.

Comment: mBytes is unsigned char mBytes[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] in obj C. lInt of course as shown above is uint64_t or long

Comment: why a negative 1? because of indentation?

Comment: Wait, are you implementing SHA1`? You can use a [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

Comment: Yes, SHA1 in a HashCash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments indicate:

"Just change uint64_t to long, everything else is the same. The capacity of long may not be enough (as there are no unsigned in Java), but that's the best you can get."

**Size of Long**

- Up until Java 7 (current): The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63-1.
- Java 8: In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2^64-1

If you need to express larger integers use BigInteger, which is a non-primitive type.